# Index was outside the bounds of the array (System.Byte to tinyint)

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql

I'm stuck
I have SP (dbo.getbalance) which returns multiple recordsets. Actually 2 recoredsets

and one of the SP's parameters is TINYINT ( lang_type ), which as i know in c# is System.Byte, but when I'm trying to pass this parameter I get an error: "Index was outside the bounds of the array"

Here is my code

```
public class Balance : DataClasses1DataContext
    {
        [Function(Name = "dbo.getbalance")]
        [ResultType(typeof(BalanceUserList))]
        [ResultType(typeof(UserBalanceAccount))]
        public IMultipleResults GetUserBalance(int iclient_no, int session_id, DateTime? bal_date)
        {
            System.Byte lang_type = 0;// Helper.GetLanguage();
            IExecuteResult result = this.ExecuteMethodCall(this,
                ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())),
                iclient_no, session_id, bal_date, lang_type );
            return (IMultipleResults)(result.ReturnValue);
        }

    }
```

and SP's parameters

```
@iclient_no         INT,
@session_id         INT,
@bal_date           SMALLDATETIME ,
@lang_type          TINYINT = NULL
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: tinyint is equivalent to an unsigned byte: 0 to 255

Comment: There is a lot going on in that few lines. What does the call stack look like when you get that exception?

Comment: http://oi59.tinypic.com/2hd9npv.jpg

here is pict of error if I understand correctly :)

Comment: The method  `GetUserBalance` only takes 3 parameters while you provide 4 in the `ExecuteMethodCall`. I assume that is the reason it borks.

Comment: rene GetUserBalance is just a method which calls SP and Sp takes 4 parameter and I'm unable to pass nullable parameter :(